# orientdb-jdbc driver: internal pool error

Tags: orientdb

I'm using OrientDB 2.2.2 jdbc driver, and using OrientDB internal pool.

When all the connections of the pool have been used, after a while the pool starts to throw this error:

```
ERROR c.c.e.s.l.ContentServerExtractorService - Error extracting data from content Server.Content Server database and on Internal Database.
com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.ODatabaseException: Database instance has been released to the pool. Get another database instance from the pool with the right username and password
Storage URL="plocal:xxx/databases/xxx"
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTxPooled.checkOpeness(ODatabaseDocumentTxPooled.java:151)
```

A search on OrientDB indicates that this was a problem that was supposed to be corrected:
https://github.com/wisdom-framework/wisdom-orientdb/issues/25
https://github.com/wisdom-framework/wisdom-orientdb/issues/25#issuecomment-112743409

The second link seems to indicate it might be an issue of a deprecated class, and i've reversed engineered the JDBC driver, and i verified that the driver uses that specific deprecated class to obtain the connection.

Is the OrientDB team aware of the problem? 
And if so, when can this problem be corrected?